# Firebase obtaining multiple documents from a collection not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using a datepicker in a food ordering webpage, the date selected by the user is stored in a variable called dateSelected, then, the following function is used to get the data depending on the date they selected:

```
const q = query(collection(db, "cities"), where("capital", "==", true));

const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
  console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
});
```

However, nothing is logged in the console. If I only console log the querySnapshot, the result in the console is the following:

`xu {_firestore: ka, _userDataWriter: ah, _snapshot: Fo, metadata: Du, query: Aa}`

I tried this:

```
const q = query(collection(db, "/Dishes/All/Lunch"), where("dates", "==", dateSelected));
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
      console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());

    });

});
```

`console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());`

This line above appears to be the line that is not working

Here's an example of a date picked that matches the one in firebase and what is logged in the console after picking it:

[image: My code]

[image: Console]

Comment: Can you try `console.log(querySnapshot.size)`? If it's 0, then that means none of the documents matched your query.

Comment: It is 0, does that mean there is something wrong with my code or with my firebase? Or does it simply mean there is not any dish for the date I selected?

Comment: It does mean no documents matched the dates. Can you share a screenshot of your Firestore document and also `console.log(dateSelected)`? It could be issue with different data types.

Comment: I believe I can't add a picture into a comment so I just updated the question with the pictures there, as you can see, even if I match the date, the querySnapshot.size is still 0, and both the firebase dates and dateSelected are strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dates` is an array that will never be equal to a string. If you want to query all lunch documents where `dates` array contains a given date, then try using [`array-contains`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership) operator instead:

```
const q = query(collection(db, "/Dishes/All/Lunch"), where("dates", "array-contains", dateSelected));
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);

console.log(querySnapshot.size)
```

Comment: I just tried this, and still, when selecting the same date as the example: "26/08/2022", the querySnapshot.size is still 0

Comment: @DavidRamirez can you please update your code with latest code that you are trying? Also, have you tried hard coding the value once like: `query(collection(db, "Dishes/All/Lunch"), where("dates", "array-contains", "26/08/2022"));` ?

Comment: I just tried using "26/08/2022/" and it does work, I also updated the question with the new code and console

Comment: @DavidRamirez so you are saying it works with a `trailing slash /`? Also, what is output of `console.log(dateSelected)` before? Do you mean to pass `finalDate` in the query instead?

Comment: Ohh my god I'm so dumb, that was the problem, now that I use finalDate it does work, thank you very much for your help